# I am trying to upgrade my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: apt, 20.04, system-installation, upgrade, 22.04

I am trying to upgrade my Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04

Software updater was not showing any new lts version

so I ran `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` to check if any update is pending to install and there were none
[Checking if updates are pending to install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaAYJ.png)

then I tried to run `sudo do-release-upgrade -c -d` to check if any new update is showing or not and I found this

[Output message of the above command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwqfD.png)

then checked the prompt in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades and it was set to lts only

[Prompt settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOA8U.png)

As it is showing There is no **development version** of an LTS available.
Do the installation need to be done from scratch.

Here is my current ubuntu version,
[Current Ubuntu Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiKEm.png)

Comment: Your second command `do-release-upgrade` did **not** include the required `-d` option   The first `-c` or check did thus it was seen...

Comment: Since the terminal message was `do-release-upgrade` to update I was only using that.      @guiverc Thanks, I added the -d and it worked,

Comment: The Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is released with the first "point" release, 22.04.01, in order to include the fixes from .01. Not available yet.

Comment: Yeah I can see why you'd do exactly what you did given the message; but I also know what was intended by the message (*you won't run the command until Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Release Notes tell you to run it, ie. what was expected by the developer*).  To change messages like that regularly involves more work, more risk of errors etc.